# Monogame distorting skinned models

Tags: monogame, skinning

I'm developing a game using Monogame and the last few days I've been trying to work with keyframe animations without no success so far.

I tried using both Xna Skinned sample from Microsoft and Better skinned sample from this [site](http://metlab.cse.msu.edu/betterskinned.html) but still my characters get distorted as seem below:
[image: you're not perfect]
(Not only my model distorts and only happens within the game, anywhere else is fine)

Both SkinnedSample from Microsoft or the Better Skinned sample  results in the same distortion.

Have any of you any clue of what (importer, processor or my own code) that could be causing this problem and what could be a solution for this?
My code is exactly like the Better Skinning sample mentioned above and uses the default SkinnedEffect.